# [Error0125] error when create new service with AXL file in ArcIMS 9.3.1[Help]

Tags: arcims, xml

i have problem to create a new service with AXL file in ArcIMS 9.3.1,when i do create a new service error message appear (error0125). so can any one help me how to solve this problem please.

this is pic shown that error message:

[image]

The picture is also posted [here](http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/4f7cef673843dee94a074f17201bd73337d71ad55abc2bbd00488794b4554f024g.jpg) if imgur.com is blocked from you site.

AXL file: [URL]http://www.mediafire.com/?3dp2sbg5yx1k4ac[/URL]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ARCXML version="1.1">
  <CONFIG>
    <ENVIRONMENT>
      <LOCALE country="US" language="en" variant="" />
      <UIFONT color="0,0,0" name="SansSerif" size="12" style="regular" />
      <SCREEN dpi="96" />
    </ENVIRONMENT>
    <MAP>
      <PROPERTIES>
    <ENVELOPE minx="-94.04178542666283" miny="28.939655671907317" maxx="-89.02180295398398" maxy="33.02342240774887" name="Initial_Extent" />
    <MAPUNITS units="decimal_degrees" />
      </PROPERTIES>
      <WORKSPACES>
    <SHAPEWORKSPACE name="shp_ws-0" directory="C:\Documents and Settings\Mustafa\Local Settings\Temp\LearnArcIMS9\VirtualCampus\LearnArcIMS9\Start" />
      </WORKSPACES>
      <LAYER type="featureclass" name="laparishes" visible="true" id="0">
    <DATASET name="laparishes" type="polygon" workspace="shp_ws-0" />
    <SIMPLERENDERER>
      <SIMPLEPOLYGONSYMBOL boundarytransparency="1.0" filltransparency="1.0" fillcolor="127,127,27" boundarycaptype="round" />
    </SIMPLERENDERER>
      </LAYER>
    </MAP>
  </CONFIG>
</ARCXML>
```

Comment: Please post the envelope section from your axl file.

Comment: please any one help me, how to solve this problem

Comment: the problem is still exist, please, i do not know what can i do with it exactly.

Comment: ?????????????????????............any one help me........please

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact shapefile you were working with, so I downloaded the parishes of Louisiana and changed the workspace to point to the new file and the envelope works fine with that file (I didn't change it). Maybe (just maybe) this can help you narrow down what the problem may be. What does the Administrator Message Console display? [image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ARCXML version="1.1">
  <CONFIG>
    <ENVIRONMENT>
      <LOCALE country="US" language="en" variant="" />
      <UIFONT color="0,0,0" name="SansSerif" size="12" style="regular" />
      <SCREEN dpi="96" />
    </ENVIRONMENT>
    <MAP>
      <PROPERTIES>
    <ENVELOPE minx="-94.04178542666283" miny="28.939655671907317" maxx="-89.02180295398398" maxy="33.02342240774887" name="Initial_Extent" />
    <MAPUNITS units="decimal_degrees" />
      </PROPERTIES>
      <WORKSPACES>
    <SHAPEWORKSPACE name="shp_ws-0" directory="C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\laparishes" />
      </WORKSPACES>
      <LAYER type="featureclass" name="Parishes_LDOTD_2007" visible="true" id="0">
    <DATASET name="Parishes_LDOTD_2007" type="polygon" workspace="shp_ws-0" />
    <SIMPLERENDERER>
      <SIMPLEPOLYGONSYMBOL boundarytransparency="1.0" filltransparency="1.0" fillcolor="127,127,27" boundarycaptype="round" />
    </SIMPLERENDERER>
      </LAYER>
    </MAP>
  </CONFIG>
</ARCXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Evan ,for helping me to solve the problem, the problem has been solved when i uninstalled OS Virtual Machine (WIN XP), after that, i reinstalled VM(xp) by virtual box pro, and then install arcims,so i tested it successfully with axl file.
thanks again for Evan.